# Print the best thresholds of multiple ROC curves in one plot

Tags: r, roc, proc, threshold

I am trying to print the best threshold in the pROC package and combine multiple ROC curves in one plot at the same time. I succeeded in doing each separately, but couldn't do both together.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)
dataframe<-data.frame (
  response= c("0","1","0","1","1","0","1","0","1","1"),
  predictor1= c(".3",".9",".2",".6",".7",".5",".5",".3",".7",".8"),
  predictor2= c(".4",".8",".1",".5",".6",".6",".4",".4",".8",".6"),
  predictor3= c(".2",".7",".3",".4",".7",".7",".3",".3",".9",".7"))
```

A single ROC curve with best threshold:

```
plot.roc(dataframe$response, as.numeric(dataframe$predictor1),
         percent=TRUE,
         ci=TRUE, of="thresholds", 
         thresholds="best", 
         print.thres="best")
```

multiple ROC curves:

```
ggroc(list(
  roc(dataframe$response, as.numeric(dataframe$predictor1)),
  roc(dataframe$response, as.numeric(dataframe$predictor2)),
  roc(dataframe$response, as.numeric(dataframe$predictor3))),
  aes="color")
```

I could not add the print.thres bits inside the list, and I also did not succeed in putting it into a `coord()` argument. How can I print the best threshold of multiple ROC curves in one plot?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.